# Is there a way to have Azure devops (build) pipelines wait for x minutes to collect/combine multiple approved PRs?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

In the situation where multiple PRs are approved within a short amount of time (minutes), the build pipeline will be started for every single PR causing a queue. On top of that, the release pipeline will start for every PR.

Is there a way for Azure devops to do this more efficient?
I'm thinking about a postpone of the execution of the pipeline for x minutes, but there might be other solutions to this.
Who can help me?

Comment: Thanks @KevinLu-MSFT for the well defined answer.The batch option seems sufficient for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for Azure devops to do this more efficient?

According to your description, these builds could be CI Builds triggered by approved PRs, right? (When the PRs are completed, the commits will push to the target branch and trigger the build )

If yes, you could try to use the `Batch changes while a build is in progress` option in  Triggers.

**Classic Editor:**

[image]

**Yaml Editor**

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - features/*
    exclude:
    - features/experimental/*
```

Here is a Doc about [Batching CI runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs).

This option can combine all commits while the pipeline is running.

To wait for x minutes to collect PRS, you could add a Powershell task in your pipeline.

For example:

```
steps:
- powershell: 'Start-Sleep -s 300'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

The command `Start-Sleep -s 300` could let pipeline wait  for x minutes. And it could collect the PRs during x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different edit form showed in my case.
Navigate to Pipelines>...>Edit>...>Triggers

[image: Edit pipeline triggers]